# traversing dom in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have code similar to the following:

```
<div class="class1">
    <a class="link1" src="...">...</a>
</div>
<div class="class2">
    <a class="link2" src="...">...</a>
</div>
```

Assuming I am currently in the click event for class link2, how do do I get the src value of the link1 hyperlink?  These are dynamically generated so there may be many instances of this code so I would need to traverse the dom from $this to get to link1.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('a.link2').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).parent().prev('div.class1').children('a.link1'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A flexible solution might be if you added a common identifier to the divs you are calling class1 and class2, you could find your parent's previous sibling. For example, instead of your HTML, you could have:

```
<div class="class1 someClass">
    <a class="link1 someLink" src="...">...</a>
</div>
<div class="class2 someClass">
    <a class="link2 someLink" src="...">...</a>
</div>
```

And then, in an onclick function on all your links, for example,

```
$('a.someLink').click(function() {
    var $someContainer = $(this).parents('someClass:first');
    var $prevContainer = $someContainer.prev();
    // now you can work with $prevContainer  ...
});
```

You would of course first want to check whether a "prev" sibling really does exist or not. You could adapt to the find the next, etc.

Good luck!
-f!

Comment: i think also perhaps you mean to ask how to get the href, not the src?? In which case, you would ask $prevContainer.find('a').attr('href')